# What verb should I use to refer to my studies?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs

When I search for the following string on Ngrams, I get no hits at all:

studied a bachelor's programme,took a bachelor's programme,attended a bachelor's programme

Nor do I get any hits for either phrase on Google, region: UK. So, now I'm wondering what verb I should use instead of "study", "take" and "attend". I've tried to come up with other ideas, but can't think of any other verb that would work. I've seen "complete" used to quite some extent, but that puts too much focus on the end result; I need a verb that does not focus on the result. More specifically, what I want to say is this:

> Between 2018 and 2021 I [VERB-ed] a bachelor's programme in economics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bachelor's programme" is not very idiomatic. One normally talks about a Bachelor's degree.

And you don't study the programme or the degree, you study *for* the degree.

> Between 2018 and 2021 I studied for a bachelor's degree in economics.

That phrase has about 100,000 hits on google.

Comment: Haha, well, this (and what Biblasia said) explains why I got no hits! In my own language it's the exact opposite; you say that you study a programme; you don't study for your degree, so that option didn't even occur to me :)

Comment: Just out of cusiosity though, If I want to say that I found the programme interesting, and I want to specify what programme I'm talking about by using a postmodifier, how would I do that? Since I can't say, for instance, "The bachelor's programme that I studied was interesting", I mean? I can't say "The bachelor's degree that I studied for was interesting", right?

Comment: I studied for a bachelor's degree. It was a really interesting course.  I prefer "course" to "programme".  There is no really need for "bachelor's"  You can say "The undergraduate course I took was really interesting".  Lots of options, just don't get too hung up on using a particular word or construction.

Comment: Course? But what do you call the nits that make up a course then? To me, "course" refers to a singel unit, which makes up a "programme" together with many other courses, but I guess you use something other than course for this then? Also, going back to my previous question: What about "I found my bachelor's studies interesting"? Would that work?

Comment: I do like "The undergraduate course I took was really interesting", but I thought you couldn't use "take" like that? But you can? It's just "study" you can't use in that way? I'm sorry for asking so many questions...

Comment: You "take" a course.  That's a natural expression.   The individual units might be called "units" or "modules" or "courses"  There is some ambiguity here, as is normal in natural language:

Answer (score 2):

In that context, the word "pursued" fits well.  If you have not completed your bachelor's, you might consider something like "worked toward"--though the word "degree" sounds more logical as the goal than "programme."